# Trying to search for a file using a variant, however its searching for just the variant "\Client" see below many thanks

Tags: vba

```
Dim SRC_Path As String
    SRC_Path = "C:\Users\Oliver\OneDrive\Client Files\Job Sheets\"
    Dim Client As Variant
    Client = ComboBox1.Value
    
    Dim DEST_Path As Variant
    DEST_Path = "C:\Users\Oliver\OneDrive\Client Files\" & Client & "\Job Sheets\"
    Dim fname As Variant
        
    fname = Dir(SRC_Path & "*Client*")
    If Len(fname) > 0 Then
        Name SRC_Path & fname As DEST_Path & fname
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Not clear what you try searching. A folder being subfolder of "C:\Users\Oliver\OneDrive\Client Files\"? A file in "C:\Users\Oliver\OneDrive\Client Files\Job Sheets\" folder, having in its name the word "Client"? Or what? If a file, what extension may it have?

Comment: Hi its a file "C:\Users\Oliver\OneDrive\Client Files\Job Sheets\" named for example SCL1234567 - Typical Project, so I created the variant Client which works under the Dest_Path, however I doesn't work under fname = Dir(SRC_Path & "*Client*") . In theory I want  fname = Dir(SRC_Path & "*Combobox1.value*"). But this still isn't working

Comment: Typical project = Client fyi

Comment: So, the answer is **a file**. No matter of its extension, its name must contain the variable `Client` string... Is this understanding correct? If so, you must try: `fname = Dir(SRC_Path & "*" & Client & "*.*")`. If an Excel file, try:  `fname = Dir(SRC_Path & "*" & Client & "*.xls*")`

Comment: Amazing mate, thank you all works now